# How to solve flowbite modal problem in vue js

Tags: vue.js, modal-dialog, tailwind-css, flowbite

I am working in Vue js with tailwind CSS, and Flowbite for component library support. But the modal is not working which is a component of flowbite. I have installed and configured flowbite as it is described in the documentation(via NPM then adding it to tailwind.config.js). Other components that flowbite I have tested are working fine.

main.js

```
import { createPinia } from "pinia";
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";

import "./assets/main.css";

const pinia = createPinia();
const app = createApp(App);

app.use(pinia);
app.use(router);

app.mount("#app");
```

modal code

```
<!-- Modal toggle -->
<button class="block text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800" type="button" data-modal-toggle="defaultModal">
  Toggle modal
</button>

<!-- Main modal -->
<div id="defaultModal" tabindex="-1" class="overflow-y-auto overflow-x-hidden fixed top-0 right-0 left-0 z-50 w-full md:inset-0 h-modal md:h-full justify-center items-center flex" aria-modal="true" role="dialog">
    <div class="relative p-4 w-full max-w-2xl h-full md:h-auto">
        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="relative bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-700">
            <!-- Modal header -->
            <div class="flex justify-between items-start p-4 rounded-t border-b dark:border-gray-600">
                <h3 class="text-xl font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
                    Terms of Service
                </h3>
                <button type="button" class="text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm p-1.5 ml-auto inline-flex items-center dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white" data-modal-toggle="defaultModal">
                    <svg aria-hidden="true" class="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close modal</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="p-6 space-y-6">
                lore ipsum
            </div>
            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="flex items-center p-6 space-x-2 rounded-b border-t border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-600">
                <button data-modal-toggle="defaultModal" type="button" class="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800">I accept</button>
                <button data-modal-toggle="defaultModal" type="button" class="text-gray-500 bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 rounded-lg border border-gray-200 text-sm font-medium px-5 py-2.5 hover:text-gray-900 focus:z-10 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-300 dark:border-gray-500 dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:focus:ring-gray-600">Decline</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where's the modal code ? and How do you add flowbite?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim, I have added flowbite via NPM.
please check the updated post, I have added modal code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not figure out this problem of flowbite in vue, then I used `https://tailwind-elements.com/` and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the following line in your "./index.html" file:

```
<script type="module" src="./node_modules/flowbite/dist/flowbite.js"></script>
```

it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You missed this part of the setup that is why.

```
<script setup>
import { onMounted } from 'vue'
import { initFlowbite } from 'flowbite'

// initialize components based on data attribute selectors
onMounted(() => {
    initFlowbite();
})
</script>
```

You have to initialise it in your component

[See the full initialisation steps](https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/vue/#data-attributes)